# Converting link to URL in text is converting email id to link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a function where the regEx handles URL in the text and converts it to clickable link. The main problem here is that it converts the Email ID to a clickable link too. I have tried to just take the www, http or https but it still considers the domain at the end and converts it to a clickable link. 
Here is my function

```
var convertTextToHTML = $("#systemNotificationMsg").text();
var conversation = convertTextToHTML.replace(/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/gi, function(text, link) {
    console.log("Link in text: "+ link);
   return '<a href="http://'+ link +'"> ' + link + ' </a>';
});
$("#systemNotificationMsg").html(conversation);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
var convertTextToHTML = $("#systemNotificationMsg").text();

var conversation = convertTextToHTML.replace(/(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})/, function(text, link) {

    console.log("Link in text: "+ link);

    return '<a href="'+ link +'"> ' + link + ' </a>';
});

$("#systemNotificationMsg").html(conversation);
```

Comment: Well this worked for email. But it ignores https:// and www. Only adds hyperlink to http://

Comment: @tkamath99 , I tried in my test this string 'testing https://www.google.com as a link and name@me.com is email' .. the output was 'testing <a href="https://www.google.com"> https://www.google.com </a> as a link and name@me.com is email'. Is that what you want ?